# Adding a description to the attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table

My question is just editing the pop-up within the attribute table to give a description. So when one opens the attribute table and hovers over the field column names, a pop-up will show giving details such as Type, Default, Read-Only, Nullable, and Indexed.

I was wondering if editing this is possible, so I can add or give a description within this attribute table pop-up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you cannot edit that pop up. You would typically write your description about your field, what it means, how it was calculated, any limitations on the values etc etc in the metadata for that field. I do this a lot and really should be best practise by all GIS users.

1. To add your important information go to the dataset in the Catalog panel right click and VIEW metadata.
2. In the Catalog tab in the ribbon > metadata group > click on synchronize
3. Now go back to the dataset in the Catalog panel right click and EDIT metadata
4. In the contents panel go to resources > fields
5. Expand the details section and you'll see all your fields and expanding them you can see a definition section to write into.

It is then up to your users to review the metadata to discover information about a specific field.